# Everything is True (Intermediate Javascript Algorithm)

Tags: javascript, algorithm

**Question**

Check if the predicate (second argument) is truthy on all elements of a collection (first argument).

In other words, you are given an array collection of objects. The predicate pre will be an object property and you need to return true if its value is truthy. Otherwise, return false.

In JavaScript, truthy values are values that translate to true when evaluated in a Boolean context.

Remember, you can access object properties through either dot notation or [] notation.

**What I tried**

```js
function truthCheck(collection, pre) {
  
  let count = 0;

    for(let x of collection){

      for(let i = 0; i < x.length; i++){

        if(x[i].hasOwnProperty(pre)){
        count++
        };

      }
    }
      if(count == collection.length){
      return true;
      }
      return false;
      }

truthCheck([{"user": "Tinky-Winky", "sex": "male"}, {"user": "Dipsy", "sex": "male"}, {"user": "Laa-Laa", "sex": "female"}, {"user": "Po", "sex": "female"}], "sex");
```

**My Request**

1. Please fix my code.
2. Please provide an optimal solution, or a "how you would have done it"

Much appreciated.

Comment: "Please fix my code" is not a question. Stack Overflow is not a place for this kind of request.

Comment: I apologise, I just started using it

Answer (score 2):

So I took some inspiration from Eugen's post. We need to go a step further and check the truthiness of each value, not just if the key exists.

```js
const arr = [{
  "user": "Tinky-Winky",
  "sex": "male"
}, {
  "user": "Dipsy",
  "sex": "male"
}];

const arr2 = [{
  "user": "Laa-Laa",
  "sex": 1
}, {
  "user": "Po",
  "sex": undefined,
}];

const arg = 'sex';

const result = arr.every(item => Object.keys(item).every(value => item[value]))
console.log(result)

const result2 = arr2.every(item => Object.keys(item).every(value => item[value]))
console.log(result2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation, if you want to check if the key is present in every object (your second argument):

```js
const arr = [{
  "user": "Tinky-Winky",
  "sex": "male"
}, {
  "user": "Dipsy",
  "sex": "male"
}, {
  "user": "Laa-Laa",
  "sex": "female"
}, {
  "user": "Po",
  "sex": "female"
}];

const arg = 'sex';


const result = arr.every(x => Object.keys(x).includes(arg))
console.log(result)
```

Your function would look like this:

```
const truthCheck= (arr,arg) => arr.every(x => Object.keys(x).includes(arg))
```

Comment: This is a nice 1 liner but it only checks if the key exists and not if the value of the key is truthy. I have added a comment taking this as the inspiration.

Comment: I don't see explicitly that being mentioned by the op, but makes sense +1 on your answer

Answer (score 0):

I will do it like this:

```
function truthCheck(collection, pre) {
  return collection.every(item => item.hasOwnProperty(pre));
}
```

Comment: Why hasOwnProperty? This is connected to an inheritance concept, so could fail during later extends.